# How can I put a line above a section heading and prevent a page break between?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, page-breaking, rules, sections-paragraphs

We have designed a class for some journal. We wanted our **section titles** to be separated by a horizontal line from the previous line. Here is the code:

```
\def\section{%
    \vskip 1.2\@bls%
    \hrule height 1pt%
    \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-1pt}{1pt}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
}
```

There are two problems, though:

1. Sometimes, when a page (or column) ends, the horizontal line remains at the preceding page (or column), and the paragraph title is printed on the new page (or column). I read something about setting some **penalty** value to fix this, but I wasn't successful.
2. We like our section titles to be **aligned left**, but LaTeX **justifies** and **hyphenates** them. Adding the command `\flushleft` changed nothing.

---

#### Edit:

Using **Stefan Kottwitz**'s excellent answer, I changed the above code as follows. Unfortunately, it still does not work: LaTeX typesets the section heading after the horizontal line, without any line/paragraph break whatsoever.

```
\def\section{%
    \begin{minipage}{7cm} %
    \vskip 1.2\@bls%
    \hrule height 1pt%

    \raggedright\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-1pt}{1pt}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
    \protect\end{minipage}%
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. To prevent a page break, you could use a `minipage` environment. The `samepage` environment could also be used. Further there's the [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) package: the command `\needspace` requests a user-defined amount of space, otherwise it inserts a page break. That can be useful for headings because they should also not be right at the end of the page.
2. You can insert a `\raggedright` command, for instance directly before `\@startsection`.

There are packages you could use:

- [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) is very good for customizing headings
- [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) is also useful, for instance for 2. the command `\sectionfont{\raggedright}` would be sufficient.

Since the `needspace` package offers a nice solution and might cause less problems, I recommend to use its `\needspace` command. Since I know you don't like to load additional packages, here's a minimal example with only the copied `\needspace` command for a demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\needspace}[1]{\begingroup\setlength{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \vskip\z@\@plus\dimen@ \penalty -100\vskip\z@\@plus -\dimen@
  \vskip\dimen@ \penalty 9999\vskip -\dimen@\endgroup}% from needspace.sty
\def\section{%
    \needspace{3\baselineskip}%
    \vskip 1.2ex%
    \hrule height 1pt%
    \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-1pt}{1pt}{%
      \raggedright\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Text
\vspace{.93\textheight}
\section{This is a very, very long heading just to test the justification}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

To verify that it works like desired:

- if you remove the line `\needspace{3\baselineskip}%` there would be a page break between the top line and the section title
- if you remove `\raggedright` the word *justification* would be hyphenated.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks. I try to minimum the extra packages needed, so the `minipage` and `\raggedright` tricks are very helpful. However, when I use `minigage`, it gives me `Missing \endcsname inserted`. What am I missing? **PS:** I'm NOT using a backslash in front of `minigage`!

Comment: @Sadeq: use `\protect` before `\end{minipage}`.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks again. It now works, but the `minipage` made the code so that the **horizontal line** and the **section heading** stick together in a single line. I edited the original question to reflect the new code; could you suggest a fix?

Comment: If you use `samepage` instead of `minipage` there would be a line break after the `\hrule` and before the title. `needspace` would cause less problems. I will edit my answer adding an example.

Comment: Oops, not everything! One problem goes away, another one appears :( The `\raggedright` not only affects the section titles, it also affects the text that comes after the title (body text).

Comment: No problem: move the `\raggedright` into the last argument of `\@startsection`.

Comment: Hurray! Now everything seems fine!

Answer (score 17):

I suggest to use the [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. It should solve both issues. Otherwise it may require more details in form of a complete but minimal example. See code below for some inspiration.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\section}{\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that the [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only used for creating dummy text thus not part of the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Obligatory ConTeXt solution:

```
% Define a frame that only draws the top frame and typesets its content flushleft
\defineframed[sectionframe]
             [frame=off,   
              topframe=on,
              rulethickness=1pt,
              align=flushleft,
            ]

\def\sectioncommand#1#2{\sectionframe{#1 #2}}
% #1 is section number 
% #2 is section title

% Ask ConTeXt to use our section command.
\setuphead[section]
          [command=\sectioncommand,
           style=\bfa, % equivalent to \large\bfseries
          ]


% Test case
\starttext
\input knuth
\section{A section with a very long title that spans multiple lines to check if
         line breaking works correctly}
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

Comment: i don't know of any actual "obligation" to add context solutions, but i actually rather like the idea.  even for those seriously committed to latex, they're a useful reminder of "the other side" ;-) ... so thanks